# MySQL not running with Promise.All in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

MySQL runs fine with simple callbacks, but I want to run multiple mysql queries asynchronously in express node.js, for that I am using async await with promise.all. I also tried using promise.allSettled, but it still gives the same error. 
Here is the complete code.

dbConn.js

```
var config = require('../config');
var conn = (module.exports = require("mysql").createConnection({
  host: config.dbHost,
  user: config.dbUser,
  port: config.dbPort,
  password: config.dbPassword,
  database: config.dbName,
}));

conn.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err.stack);
  } else {
    return console.log("Connected!");
  }
});
```

Route File.

```
var conn = require('../DB/dbConn');

router.get('/search',async  function(req, res, next) {

  try {

    const CourseContent = await conn.query( "SELECT cd.*,s.*,u.* from coursesdetails cd,subjects s,universities u where cd.subjectId = s.subjectId and u.universityId = cd.universityId and s.subjectNameEn like '%Art%';" );
    const Allsubjects = await conn.query("select * from subjects;");
    const AllCountries = await conn.query("SELECT distinct Country from worldcities;");       
    const AllDisciplines = await conn.query("select * from discipline;");

    const promises = [CourseContent,Allsubjects,AllCountries,AllDisciplines];

    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        console.log(results);
        res.render('search', { results: results,layout: 'layouts/index-layout' });

    }).catch((error)=> {console.log(error);})


  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }



  });
```

response From Promise.all results

```
[
  Query {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      packet: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      end: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _callback: undefined,
    _callSite: Error
        at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
        at Connection.query (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
        at C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\routes\course.js:58:38
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at next (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
        at next (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10),
    _ended: false,
    _timeout: undefined,
    _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
    sql: "SELECT cd.*,s.*,u.* from coursesdetails cd,subjects s,universities u where cd.subjectId = s.subjectId and u.universityId = cd.universityId and s.subjectNameEn like '%Art%';",
    values: undefined,
    typeCast: true,
    nestTables: false,
    _resultSet: null,
    _results: [],
    _fields: [],
    _index: 0,
    _loadError: null,
    _connection: Connection {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      config: [ConnectionConfig],
      _socket: [Socket],
      _protocol: [Protocol],
      _connectCalled: true,
      state: 'authenticated',
      threadId: 25,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  Query {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      packet: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      end: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _callback: undefined,
    _callSite: Error
        at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
        at Connection.query (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
        at C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\routes\course.js:59:36
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5),
    _ended: false,
    _timeout: undefined,
    _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
    sql: 'select * from subjects;',
    values: undefined,
    typeCast: true,
    nestTables: false,
    _resultSet: null,
    _results: [],
    _fields: [],
    _index: 0,
    _loadError: null,
    _connection: Connection {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      config: [ConnectionConfig],
      _socket: [Socket],
      _protocol: [Protocol],
      _connectCalled: true,
      state: 'authenticated',
      threadId: 25,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  Query {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      error: [Function],
      packet: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      end: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _callback: undefined,
    _callSite: Error
        at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
        at Connection.query (C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
        at C:\Users\myste\Documents\Office Work\FindCoursesNode.js\routes\course.js:60:37
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5),
    _ended: false,
    _timeout: undefined,
    _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
    sql: 'SELECT distinct Country from worldcities;',
    values: undefined,
    typeCast: true,
    nestTables: false,
    _resultSet: null,
    _results: [],
    _fields: [],
    _index: 0,
    _loadError: null,
    _connection: Connection {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      config: [ConnectionConfig],
      _socket: [Socket],
      _protocol: [Protocol],
      _connectCalled: true,
      state: 'authenticated',
      threadId: 25,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }...
```

Node.js version 12.18.1

Answer (score 0):

The [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module does not support the `Promise API`, so you cannot use `async/await` with it. If you want to use `async/await` then you should take a look at the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) module. Here is a small example of working with this module:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

(async function main(param) {
    try {
        const nativePool = mysql.createPool({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            database: 'newsdb',
            connectionLimit: 10,
        });

        const pool = nativePool.promise();

        const query1 = pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
        const query2 = pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');
        const query3 = pool.query('SELECT * FROM users');

        const results = await Promise.all([query1, query2, query3]);

        results.forEach(([rows, fields]) => console.log(rows));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Also, in your sample code, you do not need to use `await` before requests if you want to execute them in parallel in `Promise.all`. Because, using `await`, you will wait for each request to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it work with Promises as you want just importing the util module that already comes in node

the code would be something like this

```
const util = require('util')

conn.query = util.promisify(conn.query)
```

then after it you export the conn

But I would recommend you to use Pool instead of conn for mysql , the method I showed works also with Pool